# Compilation of Turbo C program in DOS prompt?

Tags: c, windows, compilation, turbo-c

How can I compile a Turbo C program in a DOS prompt for 64 bit?

Comment: Are you kidding? Turbo C is a 16-bit compiler that was obsolete 20 years ago.

Comment: @R, you can still get it from the Borland museum and, apparently, a _lot_ of Indians still use it (based on SO questions), though I think that's because a lot of Uni courses must teach it. Still, I concur, it's well past its use-by date.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is *no* 64-bit DOS so I'm assuming you meant the `cmd.exe` prompt.

In that case, Turbo C doesn't produce 64-bit code and may well not even *run* on 64-bit windows, given its age (though I don't *know* this).

You'd be better off getting `gcc` (free as in beer and speech) or even Visual C++ Express (free as in beer). Turbo C is a dinosaur and there's really no need to use it for anything nowadays.

Comment: Well, it's a 16-bit compiler, producing 16-bit programs. They won't run natively on 64-bit Windows because of the usual reasons :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't run 16-bit applications on Windows x64. However, you can still use [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) or a full-blown virtual machine.